# Why is an XML file with UTF-8 encoding not displaying extended characters correctly

Tags: xml, unicode, encoding, utf-8, fonts

I have an XML file with a UTF-8 encoding, properly specified in an XML declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The file includes a few characters that are outside of standard ASCII. In particular it includes the o with umlaut character. It has properly represented this as a 2-byte UTF-8 sequence C0 B6. but it displays as a division sign "÷" when opened in IE or Firefix, even when I have set the default font to Arial Unicode. The browser is correctly detecting the (explicitly specified) encoding as UTF-8.

The display looks like:

```
<diag_description>Waldenstr÷m macroglobulinemia</diag_description>
```

I could upload the file, but it is fairly large (190k) and I don't trust copy&paste not to do conversions behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you also post that line from the source?

Comment: Grabbed using Notepad++: <diag_description>Waldenstr÷m macroglobulinemia</diag_description>

Comment: Grabbed using notepad: <diag_description>Waldenstr÷m macroglobulinemia</diag_description>

Comment: Grabbed using a hex editor: <diag_description>WaldenstrÃ·m macroglobulinemia</diag_description> The key bytes are C3 B7 (which Isn't what I thought I had)

Comment: Just keep in mind that the encoding section of the `<?xml?>` declaration __should__ be followed, but isn't necessarily adhered to by the file itself.  Doesn't sound like that's the problem here though.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can tell, `ö` is actually C3 B6 (in UTF-8 encoding), whereas `÷` is C3 B7. so my guess is that you simply do have the wrong character in there.

Comment: Thank you. That is odd, but perhaps the code which renders in UTF-8 has an off-by-one error somewhere

Comment: dunno about that, but there's definitely something wrong with your hex values and the characters you're expecting.